# Which one to use "Does" or "Is"

Tags: questions, do-support

I have two sentences. I would like to know which one is correct.
Please help me to understand.

> "Is the apartment is still available to rent?"
>   "Does the apartment is still available to rent?"

Comment: Can you tell us where you got these sentences? Is this an exercise from a book, or are these sentences you are writing? That information can be very helpful; you can [read more **here**](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Comment: @J.R I didn't get it from anywhere. I just wanted send an email asking above question.

Comment: @RJay Neither is correct. Can you tell us why you want to use the verb _to be_ twice in the first sentence? This is the kind of detail we need...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use "do" as a question word with "is". "Do" means to act. The word "do" is used in questions to ask whether the action is being performed or not. While "is" is a verb, it does not describe an action.

To form a question with "is", start with the statement:

> The apartment is still available to rent.

Now instead of adding "does" as a question word, move "is" to the beginning:

> Is the apartment still available to rent?

Comment: What "do" means is irrelevant. There is a small class of verbs which form questions and negatives without "do": modals such as "can", "may", "will", "ought"; All parts of "be"; and some uses of "have" (for some speakers, all uses of "have"). All other verbs require "do" to form their negative and interrogative.

Answer (score 0):

Is the apartment still available to rent? / Is the apartment available to rent still? (Both are correct) but it is incorrect "Does the apartment is still available to rent? "

Comment: Can you edit to give a little more detail about why one is incorrect and the difference between the other two?